# The recalculated route can not show on map on Here android sdk 3.2 issue

Tags: here-api

I found an issue on Here Android SDK 3.2, when recalculation happened during navigation, the new route can not be seen on map, only white turn arrow on map. The previous SDK version don't has such issue.

It is a new Issue?

Comment: Would you be able to post a segment of code how you are handling Guidance Listener callbacks?

Comment: With our internal test apps we have not been able to reproduce this. Please provide a snippet of your code and maybe I can spot something?

Comment: I have the same issue since I updated to 3.2 as well. I disabled all NavigationManager listeners but I still have the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can workaround this regression using NavigationManager.RerouteListener

```
private NavigationManager.RerouteListener rerouteHandler = new NavigationManager.RerouteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRerouteEnd(Route route) {
        super.onRerouteEnd(route);
        map.addMapObject(new MapRoute(route);
    }
    ...
};

...

NavigationManager.getInstance().addRerouteListener(new WeakReference<>(rerouteHandler));
```